# How to query the content of a blob using .net

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to know how can i query the content of a csv file using .net. I know how to do it using Python (query_blob function), but i cannot find a similar way in .net. I would like also a minimal example if it is possible.

Just to be clear, this is what i do in Python and i would like to do something similar in .net:

```
 query_expression = f"SELECT {column_name} FROM BlobStorage {where_condition}"
 input_format = DelimitedTextDialect(
        delimiter=",",
        quotechar='"',
        lineterminator="\n",
        escapechar="",
        has_header=True,
    )
 content = blob_client.query_blob(query_expression, blob_format=input_format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just to be clear, this is what I do in Python, and I would like to do something similar in .net:

You can use the code below to query the content of a CSV file using Azure .Net SDK.

**Code:**

```
using System.Globalization;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

namespace QueryCsvExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "xxxxxxx";
            string containerName = "demo";
            string blobName = "currency.csv";

            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);
            await QueryHemingway(blobClient);
        }

        static async Task QueryHemingway(BlockBlobClient blob)
        {
            string query = @"SELECT Name from BlobStorage where Code in ('AED','AFN')";
            await DumpQueryCsv(blob, query, false);
        }

        private static async Task DumpQueryCsv(BlockBlobClient blob, string query, bool headers)
        {
            try
            {
                var options = new BlobQueryOptions()
                {
                    InputTextConfiguration = new BlobQueryCsvTextOptions()
                    {
                        HasHeaders = true,
                        RecordSeparator = "\n",
                        ColumnSeparator = ",",
                        EscapeCharacter = '\\',
                        QuotationCharacter = '"'
                    },
                    OutputTextConfiguration = new BlobQueryCsvTextOptions()
                    {
                        HasHeaders = true,
                        RecordSeparator = "\n",
                        ColumnSeparator = ",",
                        EscapeCharacter = '\\',
                        QuotationCharacter = '"'
                    },
                    ProgressHandler = new Progress<long>((finishedBytes) =>
                        Console.Error.WriteLine($"Data read: {finishedBytes}")
                    )
                };
                options.ErrorHandler += (BlobQueryError err) => {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error: {err.Position}:{err.Name}:{err.Description}");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                };

            
                using (var reader = new StreamReader((await blob.QueryAsync(
                        query,
                        options)).Value.Content))
                {
                    using (var parser = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = true }))
                    {
                        while (await parser.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", parser.Parser.Record));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code connects with Azure Blob Storage and retrieves a CSV file, then queries it using Azure Blob Storage Query.

**Output:**

```
Name
United Arab Emirates d
Afghan afghani
Data read: 3894
Data read: 3894
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Filter data by using Azure Data Lake Storage query acceleration - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-query-acceleration-how-to?tabs=dotnet)